# When I use a Bound Service in Android, does it run in the background, on its own thread or on the main UI thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sqlite, dictionary

I am searching through a dictionary in my app, and because it may takes some time, and involves searching through 170,000+ items, and inserting usually about 100 items into a database, etc..., I am trying to make it not hog the main thread. I have read conflicting things about bound services. Do they run on their own thread, or do I have to manually do that in the service? Basically, what do I have to do to run it in the background? I thought this was the whole point of a bound service. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Service runs in the UI thread, no matter if it is started or bound service, just use `IntentService` or a `HandlerThrtead` in a normal Sertvice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an AsyncTask class or just start new Thread if you don't want to do it on ui thread